# Complex queries execution using hadoop

Tags: hadoop

We have mysql database of 1 TB size. If we execute any complex query with multiple joins then system is taking lot of time for execution. Some people suggested that bigdata Hadoop can solve this performance problem. Could you please explain how this can be achieved using Hadoop cluster and what are all concepts i need to use i.e Apache Hadoop,Sqoop,Spark,Hive ?

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @nagendra, you can have a try with Apache HAWQ which is open source version of HAWQ for Pivotal HD (i.e., HDB). It has high compliance with SQL standards and high performance, especially for complex query. The reason is that it leverages MPP processing of RDBMS as well as mature query optimizer ORCA and planner.

Here are links to Apache HAWQ and ORCA:
http://hawq.incubator.apache.org
https://github.com/greenplum-db/gporca

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop and Hive can solve your problem. since Hadoop can handle large data,and Hive can query large datasets using sql like language called Hive query Language(Hive QL),complex query like joins can also performed using the hive query.Refer the link:[here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the following solutions for sql on hadoop.

1. **Cloudera Impala**:  An open source analytic MPP database for apache hadoop.
2. **Apache Hive** : Hive provides a mechanism to project structure onto the data and query the data using a SQL-like language called HiveQL. Enabling hive with tez or spark results in better performance.
3. **HAWQ for Pivotal HD**: HAWQ is a proprietary component for performing SQL queries in HDFS. Consequently, it's a Pivotal-only product, although Pivotal stumps for its parallel SQL processing and high compliance with SQL standards.